# Google Play 'Open testing' : are only the 'ratings with comment' shown in 'Testing feedback'?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app in 'Open Testing' on Google Play. I see the ratings of my users in the 'Testing feedback' section of the Google Play Console.

I see that all these ratings are given with a comment. It is quite surprising as usually most of the users give a rating only (without a comment).

Consequently, I wonder if in 'Open Testing' only the 'ratings with comment' are shown in the 'Testing feedback' section.

Anybody has the answer?

Thanks.